# Do Custom User Pool Trigger(s) fire when users are created in online console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to setup event triggers when user is created. At the moment we are creating user in the online AWS user pool console. I'm wondering if such events will trigger the custom lambda operations, namely:

- Pre-Sign-up Lambda Trigger
- Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger (to add user to group, add user data to DynamoDB etc.)

References:

- [Creating a New User in the AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-user-accounts.html)
- [Customizing User Pool Workflows with Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found the list of triggers that are specifically related to admin actions (both online and programatically). For persisting user data somewhere one has to hook into a lambda that handles the CustomMessage. Other triggers might work but I haven't extensively tested all of them.

- PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser
- CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser